Proving that $\bigcup! \mathcal{F} = \bigcup \mathcal{F}$ iff $\mathcal{F}$ is pairwise disjoint
I'm proving the following statement from Daniel Velleman's How to Prove It (p. 153):

Prove that for any family of sets $\mathcal{F}$, $\bigcup! \mathcal{F} = \bigcup \mathcal{F}$ iff $\mathcal{F}$ is pairwise disjoint.

For clarity, $x \in \bigcup! \mathcal{F}$ iff $\exists!A \in \mathcal{F} : x \in A$.
My proof
Suppose $\bigcup! \mathcal{F} = \bigcup \mathcal{F}$, i.e. for all $x$ $\exists A \in \mathcal{F} : x \in A$ iff $\exists! A \in \mathcal{F} : x \in A$. Then $\nexists x : x \in A_i \land x \in A_j$ whenever $i \neq j$, i.e. $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$, so $\mathcal{F}$ is pairwise disjoint.
Conversely, suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is pairwise disjoint, i.e. $\forall A_i \in \mathcal{F} \forall A_j \in \mathcal{F}(A_i \neq A_j \implies A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset)$. Also suppose $x \in \bigcup! \mathcal{F}$, i.e. $\exists! A_i \in \mathcal{F} : x \in A_i$. This implies that $\exists A_i \in \mathcal{F} : x \in A_i$, i.e. $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$. Hence $\bigcup! \mathcal{F} \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{F}$.
Now suppose $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$, i.e. $\exists A_i \in \mathcal{F} : x \in A_i$. By assumption $\nexists x : x \in A_i \land x \in A_j$ whenever $i \neq j$, so such $A_i$ is unique $\forall A_i \in \mathcal{F}$. This implies that $x \in \bigcup! \mathcal{F}$, hence $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \subseteq \bigcup! \mathcal{F}$.
This shows that $\bigcup! \mathcal{F} = \bigcup \mathcal{F}$. $\square$
I'd like to know (i) if my proof is valid (I think it is but if you spot an error please let me know) and (ii) how I could streamline it, as it's quite long-winded as it stands.

Immediately I notice that you have mixed logical symbols with natural language. This makes the proof harder to read than if you either only used natural language or symbolised the entire proof.

@WillFitchet Does it? I thought if one is accustomed to the notation it shouldn't make that much of a difference, and using symbols instead of words probably makes it easier to avoid ambiguities (although translations of logical symbols into plain English is fairly standard).

Symbols are fine with me, particularly in a proof like this one. I also think that writing using logical symbols can help one think about the proof as one writes it. However, having read your proof I find it less clear. For example: "i.e. $\forall x : x \in A$ for some $A \in \mathcal{F}$, $\exists! A : x \in A$." Here, you have used "for some" in one place and $\exists$ in another, and rather than putting $\iff$ or "iff" you have used "i.e." this makes the meaning harder to interpret to me than if you had used  only symbols or only natural language along with non-logical symbols.

I would instead write "$\equiv \forall x[\exists A\in \mathcal{F}(x\in A )\iff \exists ! A\in \mathcal{F}(x\in A) ] $". If you are going to write in symbolic logic, write it precisely. You could alternatively write: "Equivalently, we have that for all $x$ there exists $A\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $x\in A$ iff there exists a unique $A\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $x\in A$." Or maybe "...for all $x$, $x\in \cup \mathcal{F}$ iff there exists a unique $A\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $x\in A$.

@WillFitchet Oh I see. Yeah I guess yours is a clearer and more precise way of stating it (it follows the definition verbatim). I've modified my question accordingly.
